# How to register circular type in Autofac?

Tags: autofac, circular-dependency

I have a repository interface and class. I also have service interface and class, which depend on repository interface. Typical DI. My aim is to add caching between service and repository and not touch service or repository. Here is the code:

```
public class CachedCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _repository;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Customer> _cache;

    public CachedCustomerRepository(ICustomerRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");

        this._repository = repository;
        this._cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Customer>();
    }
}
```

I have done this with Castle Windsor. I just added the class and it worked immediately, without any registration changes. That was wow effect for me! :) Now I try to do the same with Autofac, but with failure. It complains about circular dependency and I don't know how to register it.

Edit - here is the registration:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ICustomerRepository).Assembly)
   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
   .SingleInstance();
```

Edit - here is the registration now:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ICustomerRepository).Assembly)
   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository") && !t.Name.StartsWith("Cached"))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
   .SingleInstance();
```

and after this there will be registration for each cached repository.

Comment: Please update your post with the current Autofac registration code, and the exact error message!

Comment: Autofac has a [RegisterDecorator](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/decorator-support-in-autofac-2-4/) method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a decorator, not a circular dependency. I'm going to assume the main implementation is called `CustomerRepository`. The easiest way to register this would be

```cs
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();

cb.RegisterType<CustomerRepository>().AsSelf();

cb.Register(c => new CachedCustomerRepository(c.Resolve<CustomerRepository>()))
    .As<ICustomerRepository>();
```

This works by registering the main implementation as itself, then registering the decorator as the `ICustomerRepository`. So when Autofac needs to resolve an `ICustomerRepository` it will provide the decorator.

**Edit**

Now that I see your registration code, I can suggest this if you want to avoid the manual work in the composition root. (Of course, if you have fewer than 10 repos, I would probably just use the simpler, more manual version)

```cs
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();

foreach (var type in this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract))
{
    var iRepoType = type.GetInterfaces()
            .SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name.EndsWith("Repository"));

    if (iRepoType == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    bool isRepo = type.Name.EndsWith("Repository");
    bool isCache = type.Name.StartsWith("Cache");

    if (isRepo && !isCache)
    {
        cb.RegisterType(type)
            .Named("mainImpl", iRepoType)
            .SingleInstance();
    }
    else if (isRepo && isCache)
    {
        cb.RegisterType(type).WithParameter(
            (prop, context) => prop.ParameterType == iRepoType,
            (prop, context) => context.ResolveNamed("mainImpl", iRepoType))
            .As(iRepoType)
            .SingleInstance();
    }
}

var container = cb.Build();

var repo = container.Resolve<ICustomerRepository>();
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(repo, typeof(CachedCustomerRepository));
var cast = (CachedCustomerRepository)repo;
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(cast.wrapped, typeof(CustomerRepository));
```

Comment: Thanks! With this technique it worked. I first register all repositories with one call ignoring cached versions, to avoid exception in registration. Autofac uses the latest registration. Then I need to add these two lines for each cached repository. It's manual work in composition root, but the point in here is not to touch the code.

Comment: If the "manual work" bothers you I've added an edit that shows how you can avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the example how to register. This is useful example of how, and why, to use named registration. I have wondered where it would be needed. Also, my head has been a bit limiting, because I have thought to register things on one line; and not use loops.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a wiki page on the Autofac site here explaining how to register circular dependencies](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/CircularDependencies) and which types of relationships are supported. Most likely you'll need to switch one of the dependencies in your system to be a property dependency instead of a constructor argument - constructor/constructor dependencies aren't supported.